# optimization/allocation model in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a python model that solves for an allocation model as follows: given value of x1,x2..x7 (integers) for programs (P1,P2, P3) in destination A-E provides the valuation MP1, MP2, MP3 (snapshot below)
[image]

I now have to figure out the allocation x1..x7 given a set of MP1 to MP3 valuation with a specific set of constraints. Are there any constrained optimization package in python that can solve for this problem.

Comment: if `f(x)` are linear functions, you can use any LP solver. (After replacing < by <=).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Unfortunately, f(x) is not a straight forward linear function.  I am wondering whether i need to use genetic algorithm to solve this.

Comment: An alternative would be a nonlinear programming (NLP) solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Can you think of any open source packages for solving?

Comment: `pyomo` supports a number of different NLP solvers.